# How to search blog entry only

Tags: 7, search, nodes

Hi i am newbie to Drupal, i want to search particular content type only, if any modules or ideas pleases share with some examples please.

Current search module searching whole website and returned results, but i want search option for particular content type only.

Kindly help me.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan hi where i could add (http://envisioninteractive.com/drupal/build-a-drupal-7-content-type-search-block-in-5-easy-steps/) explained functions in drupal, really i don't know, please help me

Comment: We can't explain the whole thing here for you I'm afraid :) . BTW, as I mentioned in the answer you can also achive that by using the [Custom Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search) module.